# What can cause Ansible to fail to transfer files on sftp scp and piped

Tags: ssh, ansible

Ansible was happily doing its thing on with three hosts and then one of the hosts stopped playing nice.  Now just issuing

> ansible all -m ping
> I get:

> [WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [10.2.28.25]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
> [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [10.2.28.25]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
> [WARNING]: piped transfer mechanism failed on [10.2.28.25]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
> 10.2.28.25 | FAILED! => {
> "msg": "failed to transfer file to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-12819484n3lgy/tmpcikgtk2l /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1598364743.9851992-133532194838082/AnsiballZ_ping.py:\n\ndd: failed to open ‘/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1598364743.9851992-133532194838082/AnsiballZ_ping.py’: No such file or directory\n"
> }

This sounds like the temporary directory isn't getting made.  Looking at the results of

> ```
> ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible all -vvvv -m ping
> ```

I see what looks like the mkdir running

I can manually perform scp file transfers so it seems like ssh is working OK.  What else can go wrong with just a simple command?

Comment: from the last two lines error messages from your post, you are trying to scp into a root level directory that does not exist. when you did, you logged in as a user, so the directory existed at the user level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old version of ansible then it might be the bug https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21562
You can to try fix it by defining the variable $HOME at startup your playbook

```
HOME=/root ansible-playbook ...
```

Comment: I had tried both the cfg file and env variable methods which did not change the issue.  21562 is around how the "~" gets expanded which isn't a factor in my setup.  I was running 2.9.6 and I install 2.9.10 on the control host which did not change the issue.  I also have opened up permissions on the remote node for /root/.ansible/tmp.

Comment: try to check sftp on the host

    `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep sftp`